# Printing right angle triangle forwards and backwards using asterisks?

Tags: java, recursion

Ok so this is a homework question and I'll tell you my easy problem after I explain the question.

Example: Size 4 was inputted by user. The longest row contains four "*"

Write a recursive method printPattern that will pint the pattern frontwards and backwards. The method should have a single parameter n that specified the length of the longest row in the pattern.  If n is less than 1, the method should print nothing.

And here is my program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class PrintPattern_RichardZhang
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();

        int x;
        c.println ("Please enter the largest line: ");
        x = c.readInt ();

        //calling the method printPattern
        printPattern (x);

    } // main method


    //method for printing the pattern
    public static void printPattern (int x)
    {
        if (x > 1)
        {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
            {
                c.print ("*");
            }
            c.println ();
            printPattern (x - 1);
        }

        for (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++) //Print on the way back
        {
            c.print ("*");
        }
        c.println ();



    }
} // PrintPattern_RichardZhang class
```

I don't seem to understand why for this it makes x++ every time it prints. Even thought this is correct xD. That's my question.

```
   (int i = 0 ; i < x ; i++) //Print on the way back
    {
        c.print ("*");
    }
    c.println ();
```

Comment: Try to re-think the wording of your question. Just like you don't seem to understand the problem, I doubt anyone can understand the question.

Comment: @Richard: Was you problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. However I`d write the exit condition explicitly. And for your question: On the way back it does not actually increment x. For example when x=4 initially, the function is called and 4 stars are printed then the function is called for x=3 again.However this is not the same x any longer, since x is a new local variable for every single function call. Therefore when you call the function for x=3, the previous x, which is 4 is kept in the memory (stack) for later, and a new variable x is created in the new function called and assigned to 3. This goes on until the function is called for x=0. At that point there are 5 variable named as x in the memory and their values are 4,3,2,1,0 respectively and they are all local variables for their calling functions. When the recursion halts at x=0, the paused function calls are triggered with their respective local x variable which are 1,2,3,4 respectively. Therefore, x is not incremented in reality. The x values from the memory are used in the reverse order of recursive function called. Memory works like a stack in recursion! I hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: can you explain a bit more on why "the paused function calls are triggered with their respective local x variable which are 1,2,3,4 respectively"
I don't really understand

Comment: 1 - Any function call is stored in the stack section of the RAM together with its local variables until the execution is finished and is exited. Then it is deleted. When calling your recursive function for x=4: printPattern(4) is stacked in RAM together with x=4 to stay there until printPattern(4) is exited. But before the exiting happens you call the function for x=3: printPattern(3), so while x=4 is still in the memory, a new function call and local variable (x=3) are stacked on top of that. Those two x`s are locals of their respective function and has different memory addresses.(tobe cont.)

Comment: 2 - going on the same way the stack is filled with: printPattern(4), printPattern(3),printPattern(2),printPattern(1),printPattern(0). Assuming that recursive function has explicit exit condition, for example "if(x==0) return", the printPattern(0) is returned and exited. Then the stacked (paused) function calls printPattern(1)->printPattern(2)->printPattern(3)->printPattern(4) are completed. i.e., they resume executing where they left off. E.g., printPattern(1) was paused when calling printPattern(0) and once the latter is exited, printPattern(1) resumes its execution with the next statement.

Comment: 3 - Which is printing the characters "on the way back". Remember, this second loop had never been executed on the way forward because another recursive function kicked in.  Now that the functions are exiting one by one in reverse order the executions are resuming as  printPattern(1)->printPattern(2)->printPattern(3)->printPattern(4). And that loop is executed in each of these function calls for x=1,2,3,4 respectively. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just walk through the code in your head and you will see the problem:

Imagine calling this function with an `X` of 3.

First walk through your function:

`X > 1`, the condition is fulfilled , so print `*` 3 times on a line, and call the function again with the parameter 2, `X` is still bigger than 1 so we print `*` twice now and call the function again.

The function gets called a third time; now `X` is 1, so the condition is not fulfilled and the second for statement (which for the record shouldnt be a loop, since `X` will always be 1 or less when this line is reached); will print `*` once and the function will end: So you will only have your forward triangle at this point.